# Nlog suddenly stopped creating log files on Linux, but it works on windows

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

My application is pointing to .net core framework 1.1.1.

I have added NLog to my project.

NLog - 5.0.0-beta05

NLog.Config - 4.3.9

NLog.Extensions.Logging - 1.0.0-rtm-beta1

My NLog config file is as follows:

```xml
<target name="infoInstrumentation"
      xsi:type="File"
      concurrentWrites="false"
    archiveFileName="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Logs/Punu/ServiceInstrumentation.${shortdate}.{##}.log"
      archiveAboveSize="1000000"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="10"
      fileName="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Logs/Punu/ServiceInstrumentation.${shortdate}.log"
      layout="Timestamp: ${date}${newline}${all-event-properties:format=[key]\: [value]:separator=\&#xD;&#xA;}${newline}Message: ${message}${newline}Machine: ${machinename}${newline}${newline}${LayoutFooter}"
      keepFileOpen="false">
    </target>
```

Logging works on windows, but when I test code on Linux, it fails to write.
Few days before it was working with Linux, but now it has stopped completely.

Comment: Please upgrade to NLog 5.0 BETA07 first. If the upgrade does not fix the problem then enable NLog internal logger, and check for errors/warnings. Maybe some folder permissions has been changed?

Comment: The same question on GitHub (https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/109) and the solution: "I updated to latest version of NLog and specified "nlog.config" path by using ConfigureNLog() method of NLog in Configure() method of Startup.cs.
Then it started to work properly.

NLog - v5.0.0-beta07
NLog.Extensions.Logging - 1.0.0-rtm-beta5"

Answer (score 2):

As it looks like a problem with NLog library, you may try to troubleshoot NLog. For example, you may enable NLog internal logging and check if there are any problems.

Modify NLog config: add the following attributes into `<nlog>` section

```
internalLogLevel="Warn"
internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt"
```

Look into [Logging-troubleshooting](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting)
 NLog wiki for more examples, especially read "Internal logging" section.

Maybe you have the same problem, discussed here (issue on github): [Unable to create/write to log on linux server using NLog 5.0.0-beta01 + beta02](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1737)

Comment: I enabled internal logging, but even that works only on Windows, and not on Linux.

Comment: @PurnimaNaik Again it sounds like file permissions. Try to specify a path that you know your application have write access to.

Comment: But I have given all permissions. In fact I have also enabled internalLogToConsole="true", but it fails to write to console.
And only file creation through NLog fails, by using other methods, I am able to create file at specified folder location.

Comment: @PurnimaNaik Maybe the nlog.config is not loaded properly (maybe some uppercase/lowercase thing). Have you tried to enable the NLog-InternalLogger directly within your program? Setting NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace and             NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = "Your favorite log-path".

Comment: Now it runs, but only when I run it from the folder, which is shared between my windows and Linux machine. My Linux is running on virtual box.
When I try to run it from another folder on Linux machine, NLog fails.
I am not understanding why NLog works, only if I run it from a shared folder, and other places it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your configuration filename is exactly "NLog.config". Other casing will work on Windows, but Linux has case-sensitive filenames.