# NLog works fine on windows .Net Core application but not on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, web-config, nlog

I've got this `nlog.config` file in my .Net Core console application:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\IBTest\internal-nlog.txt">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\IBTest\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\IBTest\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message} ${exception}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

When I start my application on windows it works fine and creates all log files that should be created. 
However, when I deploy my app on Linux it doesn't work.

This is how my nlog.config file looks on Linux:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="/home/ib_tests_internal-nlog.log">
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="/home/ib_tests-all-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="/home/ib_tests_nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message} ${exception}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

    <!-- write to the void aka just remove -->
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I really don't get what's wrong. I checked the paths million of times, all files (at least the ones I think) have all rights to read/write.
I've tried `dotnet publish` and then `dotnet app.dll` in windows and it worked. When I start the application the same way on Linux it doesn't. And I'm really out of ideas. Seems that all I've been doing was copy-paste from samples I had. Does anyone have ideas what could be wrong? Or what else to check? or some manual way to create that log file and see if it runs? seriously been sitting half of the day to the point I thought I'm going to be fired

Comment: Any output in `ib_tests_internal-nlog.log` ? Have you tried to enable `ThrowConfigExceptions` ? Have you configured file-permissions correctly ? Are you able to write to files without NLog ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875431/nlog-suddenly-stopped-creating-log-files-on-linux-but-it-works-on-windows

Comment: `application.dll` runs on `root` so I guess it has all permissions...

Comment: As suggested in the link I posted, confirm that the folders and file names are correct. Remember that Linux filesystem is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the filename casing of your `NLog.config` is incorrect.  Unless you have configured the code to use something other than the default, then `nlog.config` will not work, and it must be `NLog.config` (notice the capital N and L).

Comment: Today this is incorrect (it may have been true at one point). Nlog [documentation instructs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#2-create-a-nlogconfig-file) to name the `nlog.config` file as all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue. Nlog worked fine on Windows and Mac development machines, but failed to log when deployed to Linux. The issue for me was permissions (I found this out by trial-and-error, not from any errors or messages). Try adjusting permissions on the directory that is being logged to.

You are logging directly to the `/home` directory, I would suggest updating you nlog.config to use a `/home/logs` subdirectory.

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="/home/logs/ib_tests_nlog-own-${shortdate}.log" ...
```

Then set permissions with:

```sh
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/logs
```